# SMTP Server Connection Refused

Tags: smtp, localhost

After it was working fine for couple of weeks I suddenly get this error:

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25 : at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)

Any ideas what could have changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get SMTP greeting message? `telnet localhost 25`

NO => local SMTP server is not running **OR** it rejects new SMTP connections due to overload **OR** some static or overload protection rules of local firewall blocks your smtp connection

Comment: Yea I can send an email via command prompt on the server. Other thing is my application is running on the same server as the SMTP which is why i dont get why firewall is blocking it. 
On other hand, I've allowed port 25 any way.